# Set management base-path to "/" having server.context-path setted to myApp

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a spring-boot application with vaadin8 and want to change the management base-path to **"/"** but also I want to keep server.context-path to **/myApp**.

If I change management base-path to **"/"**, all the endpoints will still start with myApp/{id} for instance: myApp/health, myApp/env and so on, and that make sense because at the end the root path of my app is **/myApp**.

This is how I have configured my application.yml

`server.context-path: /myApp
 management.endpoint.web.base-path: /`

But, how can I achieve this? how can I have my management endpoints in this path **"/"** and my app context path in this one: **"/myAp"**

Answer (score 0):

`server.servlet-path: /blah`

This maps the `Spring` dispatcher servlet to `/blah`, so that your API implementations (if you used `Spring MVC Rest`) are reachable via `/myApp/blah/{id}`.

Comment: I'm using Vaadin and if I set `server.servlet-path` to `/myApp` I get this error: `Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error page location [C:/Program Fil
es/Git/myApp/error] must start with a '/'`